# Web-worker - Intensive parsing makes GUI freeze

Tags: javascript, json, freeze, web-worker

I fetch a big JSON from Java Servlet. I have to parse the JSON. When I parse the JSON from my "JS mainthread", my GUI freezes about 50 seconds and then this is parsed. This is obviously not acceptable for the user. 
So, I use WebWorkers in order to do this task in background, but when I run this task within WebWorker, my GUI freezes :(. I don't understand why .. If somebody is able to explain me ..

I fetch my JSON :

```
MandatService.list(null, null, null, null, null).then(function (res) {
    ctrl.controller.worker.postMessage({message: 1, data: res});
}).catch(function (e) {
    // Some stuff
}).finally(function() {
    // some stuff
});
```

I manage my worker's messages :

```
ctrl.controller.worker = new Worker('crg-calcul-filter.js');
ctrl.controller.worker.onmessage = function(event) {
  if (event.data.message === 0) { 
    renderUpdate(event.data.data);
  } else if (event.data.message === 1) {
    $timeout(function() {
      ctrl.view.lines = event.data.data;
      ctrl.view._.mandatIsLoading = false;
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I think the issue is with the big json. You have to reduce the json size (fetch in chunks or do paging stuff). Don't use the webworker to just parse json string, it was overhead because of structured cloning.